# ASP.Net: Password protected pages to allow access bots

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, bots

I have an asp.net webforms page which is allowed to user after logging in with username and password. Currently when an user shares a page, the login page will be fetched by facebook's sharer.php file.

below is my code in page load.

```
string fbUA = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;

            if (RouteData.Values["NewsId"] != null)
            {
                if (fbUA.Contains("FacebookExternalHit") || fbUA.Contains("Googlebot"))
                {
                    int qryStr = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["NewsId"] as string);
                    BindSingleNews(qryStr);
                    BindRelatesNews(qryStr);
                    HandleLoginMenu();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Session["UserName"] == null && Session["UserId"] == null)
                    {
                        RequestLogin();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int qryStr = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["NewsId"] as string);
                        BindSingleNews(qryStr);
                        BindRelatesNews(qryStr);
                        HandleLoginMenu();
                    }
                }                 
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/");
            }
```

I have og tags and all. I am using `<div id="divFBShare" runat="server" class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count"></div>` and binding `data-href` to it through codebehind.

How can I allow facebook share, google and bing bots to crawl such pages in webforms?

---

**UPDATE**:

`fbUA.Contains("Googlebot")` is working fine. I can fetch such pages as google in Google webmaster tools. However, facebook sharing is still not working.